# How to render a custom template for the 404 error in Slim Framework

Tags: php, error-handling, slim

I'm working with Slim 3 and for rendering I'm using [PHP-View](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View). I'm iniating the renderer like this:

```
...

$container['view'] = new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer("../mytemplatesfolder/");

$app = new \Slim\App();

$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['renderer'] = new PhpRenderer("templates");
```

I can render the templates without any problem in my routes, like this:

```
$app->get('/someroute', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    return $this->renderer->render($response, "/onetemplate.phtml");
});
```

**How can I render a custom template** (using PHP-View, not Twig) **when the 404 error happens?**

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668156/slim-3-how-to-add-404-template) using Twig, but I can't figure it out how to to do it using PHP-View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have a composer.json like that:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.0",
        "slim/php-view": "^2.2"
    }
}
```

Here it is an example application:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['renderer'] = new PhpRenderer("./templates");
$container['notFoundHandler'] = function ($container) {
    return function ($request, $response) use ($container) {
        return $container['renderer']->render($response, "/404.php");
    };
};

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

And here it is the 404.php template (please notice that it is placed under the `/templates` subfolder as specified in `app.php`):

```
<?php
echo 'CONTENT NOT FOUND';
```

:)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much friend!